# Stack overflow in xp cmd console

Tags: windows-xp

I am using an older program whose source code I cannot see. I am using the cmd.exe console in windows xp. The program ran with no problems on an xp machine last year, while a stack overflow code 2000 error was observed on a different xp machine (easy fix - use the machine that works). I tried running the program on the previously working machine lately, and now am getting the same error. No changes to the os were made and I did not change the service pack version.

Any ideas on how to get around this stack overflow error so I can use the program? Dosbox will at least open the program, however it does not run to completion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try disassembling it and looking at the code?